# Cannot create property 'from' on string

Tags: web3js, ganache

I'm trying to call a contract method from web3js. The contract is deployed in a local ganache. This is my full code

```
// Instantiate contract
const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545");
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(conf.contract.abi, "0x7167868c5e3161D9e6D0d8be564F05a432B02F5e", { gasPrice: 1, gas: 4500000 });

// Import account and add to wallet
const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount("0xa415318b6ead0170a5dab11bcdc58d4bdbf7fdcbbdb7af19f85f5da985df1d13");
// console.log(account.address) >> "0xa9C0540014C4D53E783aA94a0aE17a90b02eAe51"
web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(account);

// Estimate gas
var estimatedGas  = await contract.methods.createRecord().estimateGas({ from: account.address });
// console.log(estimatedGas) >> 26328

// Call contract method: ERROR
var result = await contract.methods.createRecord().send({ from: account.address, gas: estimatedGas });
```

The last line raises this error

```
TypeError: Cannot create property 'from' on string '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'
    at Object.inputTransactionFormatter (d:\...\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\dist\web3-core-helpers.cjs.js:78:21)
    at SendContractMethod.beforeExecution (d:\...\node_modules\web3-core-method\dist\web3-core-method.cjs.js:1075:44)
    at SendContractMethod.execute (d:\...\node_modules\web3-core-method\dist\web3-core-method.cjs.js:1006:12)
    at d:\...\node_modules\web3-core-method\dist\web3-core-method.cjs.js:1100:85
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Any clue about the error? I've got very similar code running ok in other projects, but here there seems to be something wrong and I can't find it.

Thanks

Comment: dont know why the string from accout.address is so long, it should be 40-length hex only. Can you check it!

Comment: I think that string is not the address, is the object where it's trying to assign the "from" property. I suppose is the transaction object. Instead of being an object is a string. That could be the root of the error, but I don't know why.

Comment: account.address must be string address base on this document https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#id3

Comment: Account.address is a string, and is ok. The long string you refer to is not the address, is where is trying to create the property 'from'. At least is what I understand from the error text

Comment: I mean we need to figure out why the string to create from on the error text is so long, it's very strange

Comment: Couldn't it be the string representation of the transaction object? For any reason is a  string when it should be an object. Maybe I'm stubborn with that, but that's the only explanation I see. The point would be to find out why. Anyway thanks for taking the time Ha ĐANG

Comment: what's happen if we hardcode the from address as "0xa9C0540014C4D53E783aA94a0aE17a90b02eAe51" instead of getting from account.address when calling send()?

Comment: Nothing changes

Comment: So I think it might be the problem of web3js, it's not stable! Which version of web3js you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue from web3js may help

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2376

> version 36 works well to, and if you have a typescript base, you need to use 36. But there will be a new release soon i hope

Comment: Thanks Ha ĐANG, that seems to be the issue. Not yet resolved, but still identified.

Comment: welcome, please let us know when you can resolve the problem!

Comment: Downgrading web3js from 1.0.0-beta.46 to 1.0.0-beta.36 it works

Answer (score 0):

`web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey)` creates an account object from privateKey.

Its possible to read the address from the account object.

Did you provide the correct the private key?

Comment: yeah, should confirm the privkey and the error happen on estimateGas(); not from send() as @klautem thought

Comment: @HaĐANG you should also confirm about the account object.

Comment: I think the account object is correct by this document web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#id3

Comment: As they are ganache addresses I think there's no problem printing them here. Debugging the code I get: the imported private key with privateKeyToAccount is "0xa415318b6ead0170a5dab11bcdc58d4bdbf7fdcbbdb7af19f85f5da985df1d13" and generated account address (account.address) is "0xa9C0540014C4D53E783aA94a0aE17a90b02eAe51" (wich matchs the ganache auto-generated address.

Comment: @HaĐANG Did you able to get the account adddress

Comment: account.address = "0xa9C0540014C4D53E783aA94a0aE17a90b02eAe51"